# Should I pass an objects as a parameters of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

So I have this code:

```
const failure1 = false;
const failure2 = false;

function callbackFunction(callback, errorCallback) {
    if (failure1) {
        errorCallback({
            name: 'Negative event1 occurred',
            message: ':('
        })
    } else if (failure2) {
        errorCallback({
            name: 'Negative event2 occurred',
            message: ':/'
        })
    } else {
        callback('Mission complete!')
    }
}

callbackFunction((message) => {
    console.log('Success: ' + message)
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error.name + ' ' + error.message)
})
```

And that looks absolutely awful:

```
errorCallback({
   name: 'Negative event2 occurred',
   message: ':/'
})
```

Is it even ethical to pass an object as a function parameter like that? Because right now, my brain is frying only from looking at it.

**How should I read it?** Is that an unnamed object (assigned to the errorCallback function - that is a parameter of callbackFunction) with two properties (name and message) that is later assigned to an error parameter of an unnamed function (bottom of code)? Is that correct?

I also heard that this is a really easy piece of code - is that true? Because for me that's super convoluted.

Thank you in advance, for the time spent on an answer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with passing objects as function params. You are already doing it passing function objects into `callbackFunction(callback, errorCallback)`. If the looks bother you can always create an object assigned to variable and pass the named variable as param `errorCallback(messageObject)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing Object as parameter sometimes actually makes more sense and more easy to read.

Example of a very simple function:

```
function minus(b,a){
    return b-a
}
```

Usually people will use it as:

```
minus(1,5) 
// Expected : 4, Because the latter number minus the first.
// But, it will return result of -4, without look into the function
// we do not know which number came first.
```

But if we make it an object:

```
function minus(param){
    return param.b-param.a
}

minus({a:1,b:5})
//Return : 4
//Like this, even if you don't know the content of the function
//you can still assign the correct value without knowing the order.
```